Undefined Reference to std::condition_variable::wait in ORB_SLAM3 with OpenCV 4.9.0 on Ubuntu
I'm encountering a linker error when building the ORB_SLAM3 project, which is linked against OpenCV 4.9.0 built from source using GCC 9.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. The error occurs when trying to link the mono_tum executable:
/path/to/libopencv_core.so.4.9.0: undefined reference to `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.30'

My Setup:
Compiler: GCC 9.4.0
OpenCV: 4.9.0 installed from source inside an anaconda environment
ORB_SLAM3: Compiled with CMake, using C++14 standard
Library Details:
libstdc++.so.6 version on my system: libstdc++.so.6.0.32
Confirmed that GLIBCXX_3.4.30 is present in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so

Checked libopencv_core.so.4.9.0 dependencies using ldd:

ldd /path/to/libopencv_core.so.4.9.0

Output indicates linkage to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.

Verified condition_variable symbols in libstdc++.so.6:

readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep 'condition_variable'

Symbols are present, including wait:
1348: 00000000000d96a0 8 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 \_ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE@@GLIBCXX_3.4.30


Set library paths explicitly in my environment:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LIBRARY_PATH

Observations:
OpenCV build itself does not produce errors.
ORB_SLAM3 build produces the undefined reference error.
Linking explicitly with -lstdc++ in CMakeLists.txt did not resolve the issue.
Questions:

What could be causing the undefined reference error even though the symbol appears to be present?
Are there any compatibility issues I should be aware of between OpenCV 4.9.0, GCC 9.4.0, and libstdc++ version 6.0.32?
Could this be an issue with Anaconda's environment configuration, and how can I ensure consistent usage of system libraries?

Any insights, debugging tips, or suggestions for resolving this linker error would be greatly appreciated.

libopencv_core.so looks like a 32 bit library and your research 64 bit libstdc++.so.6.

compiler too old? looks old at least.

I tried a toy project with the same settings using condition variables and everything worked fine.
